# Https rewrite via config or code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

Is there a performance difference between writing a rewrite rule like this

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Or creating an http module and doing something like this

```
public void OnBeginRequest()
{
    if (!httpRequestBase.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        if (httpRequestBase.Url != null)
        {
            httpResponseBase.Redirect(httpRequestBase.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
        }
    }
}
```

I know the code will be easier to turn on and off for different environments so the convenience of that might sway me. I just wonder what the overhead per request might be of adding an extra http module to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I create a module to the the rewrite and this worked fine.

**Other Options**

- HTTP module
- Config rewrite from IIS
- Bind HTTP website and set a redirect from within IIS
- nginx rewrite

I ended up using nGinx to do the rewrite as it made more sense for this to be part of the infrastructure than the code itself.